# How do you get 2 PWM pins to inversely bitbang at 25 KHz on a Nano?

Tags: arduino-nano, pwm

I need 2 PWM pins to oscillate at 25 KHz but they need to oscillate inverse to each other.  When one is high, the other must be low and vise-versa.

I want to do this with a Nano.

Comment: use one pin and invert it using hardware

Comment: Use two timers with the same settings, started simulaneously.

Comment: @towe: How do you start them simultaneously?

Comment: @EdgarBonet Set their Clock Select right after each other, that should only be a couple clock cycles of difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are various solutions. I suggest using two PWM channels driven by
a single timer. This way you do not have to worry about synchronizing
two timers. You can configure the channels identically, except that one
of them would be in “non-inverting” PWM mode, while the other one would
be in “inverting” mode.

Here is how I would do it: use Timer 1 to drive pins 9 (PB1, OC1A) and
10 (PB2, OC1B) in fast PWM.

```cpp
void setup() {
    // Configure Timer 1 for complementary PWM @ 25 kHz.
    DDRB  |= _BV(PB1);    // set pin 9 = PB1 = OC1A as output
    DDRB  |= _BV(PB2);    // set pin 10 = PB2 = OC1B as output
    TCCR1A = 0;           // undo the Arduino timer initialization
    TCCR1B = 0;           // ditto
    ICR1   = 640 - 1;     // period = 640 CPU cycles = 40 us
    OCR1A  = 320 - 1;     // OC1A HIGH for 320 CPU cycles = 20 us
    OCR1B  = 320 - 1;     // OC1B LOW for 320 CPU cycles = 20 us
    TCCR1A = _BV(COM1A1)  // non-inverting PWM on OC1A
           | _BV(COM1B0)  // inverting PWM on OC1B
           | _BV(COM1B1)  // ditto
           | _BV(WGM11);  // fast PWM, TOP = ICR1
    TCCR1B = _BV(WGM12)   // ditto
           | _BV(WGM13)   // ditto
           | _BV(CS10);   // clock at F_CPU
}
```

Comment: Ah, that's what I had in mind first, but I was irritated by the second Compare Output Mode behaving different for OC1A and OC1B and thought they were fixed to each other. +1

Comment: This works perfectly.  I could not have asked for a more simple and precise solution !!!